# in tensorflow how to return the index of the first matched value in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to code in tensorflow's syntax. Here is my expected function:

```
# read the first matched datum's index in a vector
index = next(idx for idx, value in enumerate(ladder) if value >= 0.99 ) + 1
```

In tensorflow, I've tried

```
a = tf.greater_equal(ladder, 0.99)
b = tf.where(a)         # It'll returns all the indices of the matched data
```

But I got no idea how to proceed cause I can't access the value of a tensor.

So my question is how I can get the index of the first matched datum before `sess.run`?

Comment: tensor would be considered as empty until you evaluate it or run it in the session.

Comment: Just simply code: index = indices[0]. It worked when I sess.run. But before sess.run, I can't use index as a scalar parameter of tf's function.

Comment: I don't know how are you using index, but do you know `b` is a 2D matrix?

Comment: Yeah. I got to know b is `2D` later. So I used `b[0,0]` as a parameter of a tf function, and it didn't work.

Comment: I have tried it what you said, and it's working for me. Tell me exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sample below. In tensorflow you first build a graph of nodes which shows what the computation is that should be performed, and then you execute this graph within the context of a session (which holds the state of the graph) to actually perform the computation.

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
data_input = tf.constant(data)

indexes = tf.where(tf.greater(data, 3))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(indexes))

# Return [[3], [4], [5]]
```

Here is the documention to [tf.Session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) but the concept of a graph and a session is also explained in the first part of the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started)

Comment: Thx for ur answer. So can't I use the indexes' first value before sess.run?

Comment: That is correct, it all depends on what you want to do with those values. If you just want to print it then this is fine. If you want to use it in a computation you can hook the indexes tensor to another tensor and use it there.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, in the below code

`a = tf.greater_equal(ladder, 0.99)
 b = tf.where(a)`

you can't access the value of b.

You can access the value of b. Before it, you should know that `b` is 2D matrix.

Since `b` is again a tensor, so you can use it in a tensorflow function. You can't directly access it without session, like you can't code like `ladder[b[0, 0]]`, before session.

But if you want to perform the same operation, then you will have to code it like below

`val = tf.gather(ladder, b[0, 0])`

Likewise, you can use the value of b.

Comment: @jmir, Is this answer is not giving the information what you need? If no, then feel free to ask.